# Laravel passing array by reference to an event subscriber

Tags: php, arrays, events, laravel, pass-by-reference

Is it possible to pass an array by reference into an event subscriber?

I have an event "user.create.show" and I want to pass an array to the event so I could modify it if needed.

The call looks like this.

```
Event::fire('user.create.show', array($data));
```

The event subscriber looks like this.

```
public function createShow(&$data) 
{
    $data['foo'] = 'bar';
    return $data;
}
```

I get a "Parameter 1 to UserSubscriber::createShow() expected to be a reference, value given" PHP error.

The line causing the error is the following:

```
return call_user_func_array($callable, $data);
```

I know I could return it the value, but Laravel returns an array with the variables and an multidimensional array if multiple variables were passed into the event. I could parse the return value but it would make my code a lot cleaner and easier if I could just pass by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using `Event::fire('user.create.show', array($data));` you are clearly passing a value since you use array constructor in the call. Change it to the following:

```
$data = array($data);
Event::fire('user.create.show', $data);
```

Also pay attention to the [notes here](http://php.net//manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and to the [solution of passing array by reference here](http://php.net//manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php#91503).

Comment: How do you access that in the listener?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i pass by reference:

```
    \Event::listen('foo', function(&$ref){
        $ref = 'bar';
    });

    $foo = 'foo';

    $args[] = &$foo;

    \Event::fire('foo', $args);

    echo $foo; // bar
```